# Django - Weekly Upload Form Limit

Tags: python, django, forms

I will create a form where registered users can upload images. I can create Models, Forms, Views. My only problem is that I want users to be able to upload 2 files per week. If 2 files are installed, I want the form to be passive. I will be happy if you can help me with how to do the limit.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. About the form being passive, you mean you want it to be disabled?

Comment: Yes, I want to be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need separate structure to store this information, first shot is:

1. Create additional model with fields: id, user_id, upload_date, file_id
2. Each time your user make an upload - add a row to the above model/table
3. And before the upload make a check - how many files were uploaded for user in the last two weeks - this is something like that:

   ```
   def can_upload(user_id):
       now = now()
       two_weeks_ago = now - timedelta(days=14)
       upload_count = UploadFileLog.objects.filter(
           user_id=user_id,
           upload_date__gte=two_weeks_ago, 
           upload_date__lte=now
       ).count()
       return upload_count < 2  # you can make constant for '2'
   ```
4. You can use above also for trunin on/off the upload form on the page - passing the result to the template.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @sebastian-opałczyński Thank you so much for your help. :)